# How to sum results of repeated subtraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Trying to teach myself maths and I realise this is a very basic question (and probably a basic concept), but I don't know how to express what I'm looking for (my Google skills are letting me down...)

If I wanted to repeatedly subtract *n* from *a*, I understand that the number of times (*t*) I'd have to do that to reach zero could be expressed as *t = a/n*

What I *don't* understand, is how I can use *t* to  sum the total of the result of each subtraction.

So, if *a* = 5 and *n* = 1...

b = 4

c = 3

d = 2

e = 1

f = 0

The sum of *b* to *f* is 10.

What I'd like to understand is how I can express the formula to find *s* when *a* and *n* are known.

So *s* = **???**

Realise I've probably not worded this very clearly, so questions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the sum of an arithmetic progression.

The formula you're looking for is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{t} (c + k n)
=
(t+1) c + n \binom{t+1}{2}
=
(t+1) c + n \frac{(t+1)t}{2}.
$$
Possibly you are only interested in the special case $c = 0$.

Comment: Thank you @andreas-caranti that's great. The fact I now know what phrase to search for as well will help me go away and understand this formula a little more too! Much appreciated.

Comment: @user2781522, you're welcome.